# How to Unzip PASSWORD PROTECTED file using Batch Script via 7Zip?

Tags: batch-file, password-protection, unzip, 7zip

I have the following batch code that currently unzips files using 7Zip:

```
for /R "%zipFilePath%" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI" 
)
```

However, I now need to unzip password protected files and I'm not sure where to pass a variable password into the current code.

I think based on www.7Zip.org, I'd have to do something:

```
-pPASSWORD
```

where PASSWORD is the password.  But I've tried a few different locations in my code for the -p, but can't get it to execute properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -pPASSWORD -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI"` should be working. What error are you getting?

Comment: haha I just answered my question at the same time as you.  Thank you for  taking a look at this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it!

To make it easy to see where the password goes, I've made it a variable.

```
@echo off
set yourZipPassword=[ENTER YOUR PASSWORD HERE]
set yourFolderPath=[ENTER YOUR PATH HERE]

for /R "%yourFolderPath%" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -p%yourZipPassword% -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI" 
)
```

Answer (score -2):

You dont need a script to unzip multiple password protected file. This can be done with this single line in the command line

```
unzip -P PASSWORD  '*.zip'
```